# How to install apg (password generator) on OSX?

Tags: homebrew

I am unable to install [`apg`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/apg) via homebrew in OSX. I tried `brew install apg` but I got `No available formula with the name "apg"`.

Tried looking around but no success so far.

Comment: Indeed, there is no apg in the homebrew repo. Can you maybe explain us what apg is?

Comment: It is a password generator. http://www.brewformulas.org/Apg

Comment: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pwgen good alternative if you want to move on from apg. This package does not seem to have active development either but latest releases are at leat less than decade ago, 2017

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `apg` formula for homebrew has been removed because the upstream software doesn't seem to be maintained anymore.  The [home page of the apg software](http://www.adel.nursat.kz/apg/) is not reachable and even [on other OS, like Debian, the package will probably be discontinued soon](https://packages.debian.org/sid/apg) (see the notice at the bottom of the description).  That's the reason why a `brew install apg` is not working for you.

That being said, if you look closely at [the discussion around the removal from homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/18111), you'll find that someone is now maintaining an updated formula in its own homebrew tap.  You can then install `apg` by first adding his tap:

```
brew tap jzaleski/homebrew-jzaleski
brew install apg
```